# System call in nasm not working

Tags: linux, nasm

I try write follow code, use int 0x80 to print number 5 but it don't print anything.

```
segment .bss
        num1 resb 1

section .text
        global _start
_start:
        mov dword [num1],5
        add [num1],byte '0'
        mov ecx, dword [num1]
        mov eax, 4
        mov ebx, 1
        mov edx, 1
        int 0x80

        mov eax, 1
        int 0x80
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

System call 4 expects `ecx` to contain a pointer to a NUL-terminated string.

So instead of `mov ecx, dword [num1]` you should use `mov ecx, num1`.